# Broadcom BCM5709C Jumbo Frames on Windows 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, jumboframes, broadcom

I have a broadcom bcm5709c quad port nic (gigabit netxtreme II); I download the broadcom utility from there site, I can setup teaming and all, but I can't seem to find the setting to enable jumbo frames at all ?

Can you please assist or provide some pointers as to where I would enable this setting ?

OS is Windows 2008R2 Enterprise Edition
2 x Quad Port Broadcom BCM5709C NICs.

Thanks and will look forward to your suggestion

EDIT :

Here is the screen shot, I have broadcom control suite application 4.0 and I can't seem to find the MTU / JUMBO setting in here, it shows me the MTU = 1500 in information tab but no edit option.

Do you think i should download the drivers from broadcom and install to see if that helps ?

[image]

Comment: Wow, BACS 4 is very different and I can't find any information on it. Yes, I would try updating to the latest drivers. What kind of server is it? Dell? HP?

Comment: FYI, the 5709 is a 2 port chip; there's no such thing as a quad port version. If you have a card with 4 ports and this chip, there are actually two chips on the card.

Comment: It's a Dell R610, so basically these aren't quad-port instead 4 x DUAL Port Adapters (giving my server 8 NICs) ? right ?

I will check the appropriate drivers for these from dell website and update them....thanks and I will report back ! :-)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the properties of the NIC itself rather than using BACS?

Comment: hi joewerty, yes I had already looked in NIC properties to see if i can set the mtu / jumbo frames from there.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Broadcom Advanced Control Suite 3](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/management_applications.php), select the head of the NIC, go to the configurations tab and look for "Jumbo MTU."

[image]

P.S. [Here's a good manual for BACS3 at Dell.com](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/network/BroadCom/R125875/en/bacs.htm).

Comment: thank you for your prompt response, I have attached an image from BACS 4.0 - ur suggestion would be v.helpful !

Comment: Hi Wesley, Thank you for your response - I downloaded the Broadcom BCM5709C drivers off the broadcom site and installed, Now I CAN see JUMBO Frame setting in NIC properties, will verify this in BACS 4 too, I am sure it will be there...I installed it on one of the server and it went fine without even re-configuring the nics so that is good it retained all config of the nics. - Thanks so much !

Comment: @rihatum Excellent! Installing new drivers is like waking up on Christmas morning!

Comment: @ Wesley, Thank you, I always build servers after downloading all drivers from Dell Support site or from vendor downloads site, this time this was build by another techie in our team and he missed this part - my fault, i should have told him :-) Now I have another question, I have a Cisco 2960 and I want to enable JUMBO Frames on this switch, its a global config command that enables jumbo on all switch interfaces, does that mean that if a client is connected with default MTU of 1500 on this switch, it won't be able to talk to my jumbo nics ?

Comment: @rihatum That's a different question, so you'd get much better answers if you asked a new one on ServerFault.